# Python style guide for default value of function argument

Tags: python

Without creating instance as default value:

```
def foo(v1=None):
  if v1 is None:
    v1 = Foo()
```

Create instance as default value:

```
def foo(v2=Foo()):
```

Which way is preferred in python style?

Comment: If `Foo` is mutable (which probably is the case here), then the first one. If you somehow ensure that `Foo` is immutable, then the second one is also okay.

Comment: @rdas or you never plan to mutate it...

Comment: In any case, *this is not a style issue*. These are two semantically different things going on here

Comment: Right @juanpa.arrivillaga - though I would stress that planning on something doesn't necessarily mean it will never happen. I'd breath easier if I knew that `Foo` was immutable if ihad used it in the second way

Comment: @rdas why? What if you *intended* it to be mutable and to be re-used? Again, the issue here is that the semantics are different, and whether or not that is appropriate *is not an issue of style*

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean "keeping something mutable without ever intending mutate it" is less safe than "making something immutable to begin with". If you need your object to be mutable, then the second option is semantically different as you pointed it out.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to create a new instance every time you call the function, this works:

```
def foo(v1=None):
    if v1 is None:
        v1 = Foo()
```

And this wouldn't work:

```
def foo(v2=Foo()):
    pass
```

Why? Because default argument values are evaluated only once per module load, which usually happens when a program starts up. After the module containing this code is loaded, the default argument will never be evaluated again.

Comment: Why is that "incorrect"? What if that is what you *intended*? The issue here is that these two different definitions *have different semantics*, so it is *correct or incorrect* depending on what you *intended*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point. I updated the answer, thanks

Comment: Thank you @DavidRobles. I just verified with a small experiment. Yes you are right. The 2nd way always uses the same reference when foo() is called multiple times.